# python ctypes returns zero as first element in array?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, numpy, ctypes

I have a simple python script using ctypes that passes an array pointer to an external function. The external function is then simply meant to pass the same array back to python (this is meant as a simple unit test to ensure python and the external function are both using the same values). The function prototype looks like this:

```
void Array_tmp(int32_t Array[], int32_t *len, int32_t Array2[])
```

and the python script looks like this:

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np
import numpy.ctypeslib
import os

dll = 'array_test.dll'

loadlib = cdll.LoadLibrary(dll)

arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
length = len(arr)

c_arr = np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(arr)
clen = c_int32(length)
p_clen = pointer(clen)
c_arr_ptr = cast(c_arr, POINTER(c_double))
loadlib.Array_tmp.argtypes = [type(c_arr_ptr), type(p_clen)]
loadlib.Array_tmp.restype = type(c_arr)

g = loadlib.Array_tmp(c_arr_ptr, p_clen)
print(g)
np_arr_g = np.ctypeslib.as_array(g)
print(np_arr_g)
```

The output from the script looks like this:

```
<numpy.ctypeslib.c_long_Array_5 object at 0x044A7AD0>
[0 2 3 4 5]
```

Why is the first element of the array showing up as zero instead of one, while all the others are correct?

EDIT: Changing the line `c_arr_ptr = cast(c_arr, POINTER(c_double))` to `c_arr_ptr = cast(c_arr, POINTER(c_int32))` has no effect on the output aside from perhaps a slight change in the memory address.

Comment: *everything* is wrong with this code. Your function has **3** arguments, not 2, and it returns `void` not an "array" whatever it would be.  Also, if the function takes a pointer to `int32_t`, and you supply a pointer to `double`, behaviour is wholly undefined.

Comment: So the third argument should be the output of the function. Is there another way to access that from python if the output is technically void?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues with the code presented.  Here's a working example:

**test.c**

```
#include <memory.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define API __declspec(dllexport) /* Windows-specific export */

/* FYI: No reason for 'len' to be a pointer */
API void Array_tmp(int32_t Array[], int32_t *len, int32_t Array2[])
{
    memcpy(Array2,Array,*len * sizeof(int32_t));
}
```

**test.py**

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np

dll = CDLL('test')

# Good idea to declare the functions arguments and return type fully for error checking.
func = dll.Array_tmp
func.argtypes = POINTER(c_int32),POINTER(c_int32),POINTER(c_int32)
func.restype = None

# Create input array and output array of same size.
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
out_arr = np.zeros(arr.shape,dtype=np.int32)

# Get everything as a ctypes object
c_arr = np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(arr)
c_out_arr = np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(out_arr)
clen = c_int32(len(arr))

func(c_arr,byref(clen),c_out_arr)

# Original output array of zeros is now modified
print(out_arr)
```

**Output:**

```
[1 2 3 4 5]
```